# How to make customised hot keys in wpf application and perform various operations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, global-hotkey

How to make customised hot keys in wpf application and perform various operations like making fields editable, save the window, go to a field index.

I am working on a wpf application that holds three windows + 1 main window. I am showing the hot keys shortcuts on the main window so those are visible on all the windows. Now I want to make the application perform the operation based on the keys I am hitting as hotkey combinations.

I have written the code but when I am running the application in debug mode the `Window_KeyDown()`  method gets hit on first ever key hit. For example if I hit `Alt+F` then the code gets on Alt itself which gets into `Keyboard.Modifiers` .

1. Code in mainwindow.xaml.cs

   private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
   e.Handled = true;
   var modifiers = Keyboard.Modifiers;
   var key = e.Key;

   ```
       if (key == Key.System)
       {
           key = e.SystemKey;
       }

       if (key == "C")
       {
           //make all the fields of the Window editable;
       }
       else if ((key == Key.D) && (modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt))
       {
           //Perform delete operation
       } }
   ```
2. Code in mainwindow.xaml

> <Window x:Class="Namespace.MainWindow" Name="mainWindow"

```
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ApplicationName"
    Background="Black"
    Foreground="White"
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
    d:DesignHeight="846.706"
    d:DesignWidth="857.544"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    >
```

3. On window otherthan mainwindow

I am also trying to perform operation on single key hit. For example when I press 'C' my window fields' property= Isreadonly sets to false, by default I am setting it to true for textbox type field.
This style property I am setting under each .XAML file for the three windows.

```css
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="txtRow1Style"><Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"></Setter><Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"></Setter><Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter><Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter><Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"></Setter><Style.Triggers><DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NameSpace.MainWindow.Key}" Value="C"><Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"></Setter></DataTrigger></Style.Triggers></Style>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keybinding?view=netcore-3.1
is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thanks Athul, could you help me with any implementation example??